# Inconsistency of interpreting TableForm inputs

Tags: bugs, list-manipulation, input-forms

**Bug introduced in 12.3.1 or earlier and persisting through 13.2.0 or later.**

---

Consider this line of code and its result:

```
TableForm[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, TableHeadings -> {None, {1, 2}}]
```

[image: table-form of a list]

As you see, when I assign the output of `TableForm` to a variable, it is saved as a `List`. But when I restart the kernel by executing `Quit` and run the second line, it returns:

```
{None,OutputFormsDump`HeadedColumns}[{{1,2},{a,b},{c,d}}]
```

So it seems that you have to execute a `TableForm` command somewhere in your code before assigning a list in table-from! Currently, I use a rather ugly hack like this:

[image: table-form fix]

which checks the `Depth` of a simple table before executing the assignment. If tables are not interpreted as list, then it prints a temporary `TableForm` and after that, all table inputs will behave as lists.

> Why does this happen? Is this a feature or a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

Comment: `t = {{a, b}, {c, d}}` and `x = TableForm[t, TableHeadings -> {None, {1, 2}}]` .  The `*Form` functions are for display only and their outputs cannot be used in subsequent computation. For computation, evaluate and use `t`.

Comment: I already said what has "worked" for me @Bill. The question is [something else](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254341/5358284).

Comment: @Syed - `TableForm` is for display **and** interpretation. Evaluate `TableForm[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]` in a notebook and it displays nicely, then in a new cell evauate `InputForm[%]` and you see the `TableForm` is interpreted as the underlying matrix.

Comment: This certainly seems like a bug to me

Comment: @JasonB.  Thanks for the correction. I assumed (incorrectly) that it worked like `MatrixForm`.